# ASP.NET MVC 5 Edit Action - How to write to Multiple DB Tables/Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping

Is there any way to somehow combine the data from two models and THEN map them *both* to the same viewModel in the context of an edit action?

I have never had to update several tables at once in an edit action in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework 6.1.3. This is the layout:

I have a DB table called "Address" which has fields for StreetNumber, StreetName, City, State, ZipCode. It has a *one-to-one* relationship with another table called Bars. As in, a bar can only have one address and one address can only have one bar.

Because I am storing this data in two separate tables, I am having a very difficult time trying to successfully implement an Edit action which takes data from **one form** (BarForm) and should update both the Bar and Address database tables. See my code:

**BarController**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            var bar = _context.Bars.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            var address = _context.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(a => a.BarId == id);
            //Make sure that the id actually exists:
            if (bar == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Bar, BarFormViewModel>(bar, new BarFormViewModel());
            if (address == null)
            {
                address = new Address();
            }
            Mapper.Map<Address, BarFormViewModel>(address, viewModel);

            viewModel.IsNew = false;

            return View("BarForm", viewModel);
        }
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save(BarFormViewModel bar)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var viewModel = Mapper.Map<BarFormViewModel, BarFormViewModel>(bar, new BarFormViewModel());
                viewModel.IsNew = false;
                return View("BarForm", viewModel);

            }
            if (bar.Id == 0)
            {

                var newbar = Mapper.Map<BarFormViewModel, Bar>(bar);
                newbar.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                _context.Bars.Add(newbar);
                var addressToAdd = Mapper.Map<BarFormViewModel, Address>(bar);
                _context.Addresses.Add(addressToAdd);

            }
            else
            {
                var barInDb = _context.Bars.Single(b => b.Id == bar.Id);
                var addressInDb = _context.Addresses.Single(a => a.BarId == bar.Id);
                Mapper.Map<BarFormViewModel, Bar>(bar, barInDb);
                Mapper.Map<BarFormViewModel, Address>(bar, addressInDb);

            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bar");
        }
```

**Domain Models:**

```
public class Bar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }
        public string SundayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string MondayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string TuesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string WednesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string ThursdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string FridayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string SaturdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }

 public class Address
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Number { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }

        public Bar Bar { get; set; }
        public int BarId { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Model which includes both Address and Bar properties**:

```
{
    public class BarFormViewModel
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Google Place ID")]
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Sunday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string SundayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Monday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string MondayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tuesday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string TuesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Wednesday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string WednesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Thursday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string ThursdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Friday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string FridayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Saturday Happy Hour Info:")]
        public string SaturdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }


        //Address Model Info
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
        public int? Number { get; set; }
        public string StreetName { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int? ZipCode { get; set; }

        public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    }
```

The problem here is that I am getting an empty AddressId with this setup, which is causing an exception when the Save action gets run. This is because the BarForm view is getting passed a ViewModel which has been mapped from a Bar object and the Bar domain model actually has no Address information in it, since it is not the Address model/table.

Is there any way to somehow combine the data from both the Address and Bar models and THEN map them *both* to the same viewModel?

I keep getting a Sequence Contains no Elements error for this line in the Save action:

```
var addressInDb = _context.Addresses.Single(a => a.Id == bar.AddressId);
```

I also tried:

```
var addressInDb = _context.Addresses.Single(a => a.BarId == bar.Id);
```

Neither work. I understand what the error is saying and have also checked the actual HTML for my hidden Addressid field and it is blank... See code in my BarForm View:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddressId)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `new BarFormViewModel()` as the second parameter in your mapping calls as it is not necessary.

In your post action, inside your if statement that checks if the ModelState is valid and if bar.Id == 0, bar is already a view model, so no need to mapping.

And when you create your AutoMapper mapping, you must create a custom property mapping because the Address.Id property will not map automatically to the AddressId property as the name is not the same.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Address, BarFormViewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.AddressId, o => o.MapFrom(source => source.Id));
```

And then do the same for the inverse mapping.